CcHttpServer: Failed to create gst elements (GNOME NETWORK DISPLAY)
I am tried to install following the instructions here https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu
linux@dell ~> flatpak run org.gnome.NetworkDisplays

(gnome-network-displays:2): Gnd-ERROR **: 19:03:03.137: CcHttpServer: Failed to create gst elements

Trying to connect my Smart-TV (Olive 4k Android TV that uses Fascast software) but fails with the aforementioned error
My
More info on my environment here:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SNj7tBwRQQ/
Best Regards
UPDATE
linux@dell> flatpak uninstall org.gnome.NetworkDisplays


        ID                                        Branch         Op
 1. [-] org.gnome.NetworkDisplays                 stable         r
 2. [-] org.gnome.NetworkDisplays.Locale          stable         r

Uninstall complete.
linux@dell> sudo apt install gnome-network-displays
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-network-displays

I tried but throwing the aforementioned error

I use the flatpak version of gnome display manager and got the same problem. After uninstalling the flatpak version and use back the Ubuntu version then everything is working. I just ran these two lines of code:
flatpak uninstall org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
sudo apt install gnome-network-displays

Hope this helps

I was not able to fix it. I copy pasted my screen output in my UPDATE section of question

After checking https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/ppc64el/gnome-network-displays for the package, I guess it was not included in Ubuntu 22.04 but in 24.04. Would you consider upgrading Ubuntu? Alternatively you could you Google Chrome to cast your screen onto your TV
